# Custom case validation error using trigger

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I want restrict users adding more than 500 children cases to a parent case. I cannot do it with validation rule.

Only way is trigger, can somebody help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you implement [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), you can do it with a `Validation Rule` after all. Create a field called `Child_Count__c` and craft a `Lookup Rollup Summary` along the lines of:

[image: [Parent Object:Case;Relationship Field:ParentId; Child Object:Case;]

Then your validation rule would just be:

```
Child_Count__c > 500
```

You don't need a ton of apex, though.

```
public static final Integer MAX_CHILDREN = 500;
public static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Too many child cases';

public static void validateChildCount(List<Case> newCases)
{
    Map<Id, List<Case>> byParent = groupByParent(newCases);
    for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
        SELECT ParentId, count(Id) children FROM Case
        WHERE ParentId IN :byParent.keySet()
        GROUP BY ParentId HAVING count(Id) > 0
    ])
    {
        Id parentId = (Id)aggregate.get('ParentId');
        Integer existingChildren = (Integer)aggregate.get('children');
        Integer newChildren = byParent.get(parentId).size();
        if (existsingChildren + newChildren > MAX_CHILDREN)
            for (Case newCase : byParent.get(parentId)) newCase.addError(ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
public static Map<Id, List<Case>> groupByParent(List<Case> newCases)
{
    Map<Id, List<Case>> byParent = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();
    for (Case newCase : newCases)
    {
        if (!byParent.containsKey(newCase.ParentId))
            byParent.put(newCase.ParentId, new List<Case>();
        byParent.get(newCase.ParentId).add(newCase);
    }
    return byParent;
}
```

Then, you can just pass `trigger.new` to the `validateChildCount` method from your `before insert` trigger.

**Update**

If you want to update, take a look at the `Selector` [library](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector).

```
public static Select.Filter hasParentChanged()
{
    return Select.Field.hasChanged(Case.ParentId);
}
```

Then, your trigger might look something like:

```
trigger AllCase on Case (before insert, before update)
{
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert)
        {
            CaseServices.validateChildCount(trigger.new);
        }
        if (trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            CaseServices.validateChildCount(
                CaseServices.hasParentChanged()
                    .filter(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I usually use a handler pattern to keep code out of the trigger body, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the response Adrian. I don't think dlrs can be implemented right now on my org. May be I can consider it for later release.

Comment: Any other way ?

Comment: @MuthuSamy Yeah I guess it's not a ton of code. You'll have to write your own tests!

Comment: Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments at line 16 column 13 -- couldn't resolve this error, what's missing here !!!

Comment: @MuthuSamy er...tried to add the `List<Case>` instead of its `size()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works great for insert. I'm concerned about update. sometimes cases will be created and will be associated later. What would be your advise on this ? sorry for repeated questions, I'm not much into apex, getting use to it.

Comment: @MuthuSamy Why would you care about `update`? Reparenting?

Comment: Yes, If case is created without parent and if it is re-parented later. ultimately the purpose is defeated. So I want to restrict the users adding child cases during update as well. current code checks only during insert. If I add before update event to the code, it's blocking updating the parent record it self. not sure what's wrong. 

trigger blockchild on Case (before insert,before update) {

if (Trigger.isInsert){
    validateChildren.validateChildCount(trigger.new);
    }
  //  else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
  //  validateChildren.validateChildCount(trigger.new);
  //  }

}